# list index out of range while removing indexes from list

Tags: python

for y in range(len(List)):
            print("length",len(List))
            print ("y",y)
            print("List",List[y])
            if (List[y])%(dividing_prime)==0:
                  print(List[y])
                  counter=counter+1
                  List[y]=0
                  List.remove(0)

Comment: What is that link for? If you have code, post it here, as text.

Comment: the code was not posting when i typed it

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying a list while iterating over it. Because of that, the list is changing in size while you are iterating cause an index out of bounds.

What you could do is create another list from the elements you don't want to remove.

```
new_list = [x for x in mylist if not remove(x)]
```

If you want to keep the same list and not create a new copy then you could use the slice operator.

```
mylist[:] = [x for x in mylist if not remove(x)]
```

The itertools library also provides a tool to do this called filterfalse
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse